# ROS2 Managed node: triggering an error from primary state

Tags: ros, ros2, node

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a managed node with a thread running when it is in `ACTIVE ' state.

During the execution of the thread an error can occur  and I have not understood how to trigger an error event to enter into the `on_error` callback, manage the error and going back to `UNCONFIGURED ' state if the error can be solved.

`on_error` callback is executed when a transition callback returns `TRANSITION_CALLBACK_ERROR` or an unhandled exception is generated... but when the node is in a Primary state?

Thank you
Walter

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/302178/ros2-managed-node:-triggering-an-error-from-primary-state/) by [Myzhar](https://answers.ros.org/users/455/myzhar/) on ROS Answers with karma: 541 on 2018-08-31

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There is no error handling done when a transition is executed successfully. The underlying state machine only handles the transitions, but not the primary states.
So you might want to catch exceptions in your primary states yourself and then trigger a change of state manually.
https://github.com/ros2/rclcpp/blob/master/rclcpp_lifecycle/include/rclcpp_lifecycle/lifecycle_node.hpp#L408-L468

---

Originally posted by [Karsten](https://answers.ros.org/users/8211/karsten/) with karma: 643 on 2018-09-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Myzhar](https://answers.ros.org/users/455/myzhar/) on 2018-09-04**:
The design page speaks about the possibility of entering in 'error handling' from the primary state.
Do you think that it will be added?

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I didn't find this question before I asked [my duplicate question](https://answers.ros.org/question/348583/ros-2-lifecycle-node-self-transitioning/), but after digging and finding it impossible, I have created a series of pull requests implementing this functionality: [rcl_interfaces#97](https://github.com/ros2/rcl_interfaces/pull/97), [rcl#618](https://github.com/ros2/rcl/pull/618), [rclcpp#1064](https://github.com/ros2/rclcpp/pull/1064), and to show how it is used, [demos#436](https://github.com/ros2/demos/pull/436).

---

Originally posted by [thebyohazard](https://answers.ros.org/users/1483/thebyohazard/) with karma: 3562 on 2020-04-16

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [longjie0723](https://answers.ros.org/users/31799/longjie0723/) on 2023-03-31**:
I also hope that this issue will be resolved. I believe that this feature is essential for practical use of the Lifecycle.